# Is bulkIndexOnStartup needed when using mirrorChanges = true in Grails Searchable plugin?

Tags: grails, lucene, grails-orm, searchable, compass-lucene

The mirrorChanges option will mirror all changes made through GORM/Hibernate, so if I'm not making any external changes to the database, then is bulkIndexOnStartup needed?

The problem is that our data set is very large (>1M rows) and the bulk indexer may take 30+ minutes.

When set to 'fork' lucene will crash if any changes are made though the GORM, because lucene is not thread safe and the GORM transaction will attempt to update the index while the forked bulk index thread is running.

When set to true, the application will finish initializing for those 30+ minutes.

Comment: have you actually seen the bulk indexer crash when forking it on startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not modifying the data from another source, then you don't need to set bulkIndexOnStartup to true, specially if you set mirrorChanges to true. This is pretty much how we handle it in our application. We have a controller action that calls the indexer, forked, for a specific class so we can call it on demand in case we need to, for example if for some reason we needed to update the database directly. We then call the indexer for a specific class and not the entire set of class, in that way if we need to call it then it won't take that long.

Answer (score 0):

bulkIndexOnStartup should not be needed if you are mirroring changes.

we have a much smaller dataset so we actually do bulkIndexOnStartup with 'fork' set as an option when we do releases as more of a maintenance task